# pyqt4 button click event open new frame/window

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am a newbie to Python GUI programming. Currently I am trying to create buttons where once I clicked on it, it should open a new window/frame.

This is my python GUI code:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(QPalette.Background,QBrush(QPixmap("blue-gradient-2.jpg")))
        self.setPalette(palette)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 600, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle("Testing Window")
        # self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(''))
        self.home()


    def qr(self):
        backbtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Back" , self)
        backbtn.clicked.connect(home)
        backbtn.resize(100, 100)
        backbtn.move(100, 100)
        self.show()

    def home(self):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("QR Code", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(qr)

        btn.resize(100, 100)
        btn.move(100, 100)

        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Face Recognition", self)
        btn1.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

        btn1.resize(200, 100)
        btn1.move(300, 100)

        self.show()


def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Actually, this code I took from a tutorial. I saw even Tkinter can open a new window/frame. But there isn't any tutorial on the PyQt opening a new window/frame.

The error I am getting is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyqt.py", line 47, in <module>
    run()
  File "pyqt.py", line 44, in run
    GUI = Window()
  File "pyqt.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.home()
  File "pyqt.py", line 28, in home
    btn.clicked.connect(qr)
NameError: global name 'qr' is not defined
```

I am sure there should be a appropriate way to deal with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you haven't defined a global function `qr()`. But since you have defined a method with the same name, I suspect your intention was to do

```
btn.clicked.connect(self.qr)
```

The same accounts for `home()` in your `qr` method

```
backbtn.clicked.connect(self.home)
```

To open a new window with PyQt4 it is as easy as calling `widget.show()` on a widget without a parent.

Comment: Well that helps to solve my error but when I click to open the new window its now working can i knnow why..

Comment: @raaj5671 `self.show()` won't work, since the window is already shown. You need to create a new and independent window and show that one,

Comment: which means i have to create a new class?

Comment: @raaj5671 for example. Or a new instance. There're many ways to achieve this. It's up to you. You're the programmer.